# A conjectured upper bound for $\left(\frac{x^n+1}{x^{n-1}+1}\right)^n+\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)^n$ and $x\geq 1$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, inequality, examples-counterexamples, conjectures

Hi I have (related https://mathoverflow.net/questions/337457/prove-that-left-fracxn1xn-11-rightn-left-fracx12-rightn ):

> > Let $x\geq 1$ a real number and $n\geq 2$ a natural number then we have :
> >     $$\Big(\frac{x^{n+1}+1}{x+1}\Big)\Bigg(\frac{\Big(\frac{x+1}{2}\Big)^n}{\Big(\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}\Big)^n}+\frac{(x^n+1)^2}{(x^{n-1}+1)(x^{n+1}+1)}\Bigg)\geq \left(\frac{x^n+1}{x^{n-1}+1}\right)^n+\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)^n$$

It's a conjecture so I have tested for $n\leq 20$ . Maybe it works also for $n$ a positive real number . If it's true I think we can make something similar to the Peter Mueller's answer. For the case $n=3$ [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative%20%28x%5E%284%29%2B1%29%2F%28x%2B1%29%20%28%28%28%28x%2B1%29%2F%282%29%29%5E%283%29%29%2F%28%28%28x%5E%282%29%2B1%29%2F%28x%2B1%29%29%5E%283%29%29%2B%20%28%28x%5E%283%29%2B1%29%5E%282%29%29%2F%28%28x%5E%284%29%2B1%29%20%28x%5E%282%29%2B1%29%29%29-%28%28x%5E%283%29%2B1%29%2F%28x%5E%282%29%2B1%29%29%5E%283%29%2B%20%28%28x%2B1%29%2F%282%29%29%5E%283%29) we have the derivative . Clearly the numerator (of the derivative) is positive for $x\geq 1$.But in some way it's not so easy with the general case .

So how to solve it ?

Any helps is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for all your contribution .